# Do controllers of angular-ui-router views cause $scope.$watch not to fire?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

To explain the issue please take a look at the following `states`:

```
.state('app.play.lobby', {
            url: '/lobby',
            resolve: {
                games: function (FirebaseAdapter) {
                    return FirebaseAdapter
                        .syncArray('disciplines')
                        .$loaded()
                        .then(function (list) {
                            return list;
                        });
                },
                tournaments: function (FirebaseAdapter) {
                    return FirebaseAdapter
                        .syncArray('tournaments')
                        .$loaded()
                        .then(function (list) {
                            return list;
                        });
                }
            },
            views: {
                filter: {
                    templateUrl: 'play/lobby/filter.tpl.html',
                    controller: LobbyFilterController
                },
                browser: {
                    templateUrl: 'play/lobby/browser.tpl.html',
                    controller: LobbyBrowserController
                }
            }
        });
```

Everything is working fine. The problem is: In the controller `LobbyFilterController` I'm using `$scope.$watch()` to listen to a change of an object. But **the `$watch()` command is fired only once, which is after the state has been successfully loaded**. As soon as the state is loaded and I change a value of an attribute inside the object, nothing happens.

**LobbyFilterController**

```
function LobbyFilterController($scope, games, TournamentFilter) {
    $scope.filter = {
        game: null,
        mode: 'regular',
        type: 'all',
        format: 'all',
        eliminationMode: 'all',
        gridsize: 'all',
        status: 'all',
        groupstage: false,
        reshuffledGrid: false,
        password: false
    };

    $scope.$watch($scope.filter, function(data) {
        console.log('filter changed...');
    }, true);
}
```

This behaviour doesn't change when I try using a normal value such as $scope.myVar. Since the event fires once after loading, I guess I haven't made a mistake (hopefully I'm wrong)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide watching property (or [watch expression](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch)) as string or a function expression that returns a value. Instead you are setting an object. try change it to:

```
$scope.$watch('filter', function(data) {
    console.log('filter changed...');
}, true);
```

$watch uses [`$parse` to create](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/rootScope.js#L360) a getter out of the provided expression. And what you have provided is an object as expression which will just get  ignored as it looks for only string or function. Look at the [case statements at the source](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/parse.js#L1039). And all the watchers will fire atleast once to kick off dirty checking during digest cycle which happens in your case too, and if you look up the arguments in the first execution you will see that both the values are undefined, because there was nothing really watched or the watcher always will return `undefined` with the overridden angular.noop function.

Comment: And I thought I read the API carefully, sigh. Thanks, it works.